# CSRF Token problem when I add dropzone to an existing form in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, dropzone.js, django-csrf

I'm working with a Django form using dropzone to upload images. But I don't want to add the dropzone to the entire form, just to a div of it. Here is the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<h6>UPLOAD MULTIPLE IMAGES NOW</h6>
<br>
<div class="formdiv" style="width:100%">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload/" methd="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <label for="yourname">Yourname
            <input type="text" value="name" />
        </label>
        <div class="dropzone dz" id="my-dropzone">
            <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span>{% trans "Drop here or click to upload" %}</span></div>
            <div class="fallback">
                <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that when I try to upload any image I get a Forbidden error message with the following text:

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

Notice that if I remove the `class="dropzone dz" id="my-dropzone"` from the div and I put it inside the `<form>` tag instead, everything will work. The problem began exactly when I moved dropzone in a div because I didn't want it to apply to the whole form.

Here is my dropzone configuration code:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover=false;
const myDropzone = new Dropzone('#my-dropzone',{
    url:'upload/',
    maxFiles:15,
    maxFilesize:5, // 5 mb max
    //parallelUploads:2,
    // if image is horizontal, then resize it if it's more than resizeWidth
    resizeWidth:1024,
    // if the image is vertical, then resize if it's more than resizeHeight
    resizeHeight:1024,
    // also they can be mime such as image/png
    acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg,.webp",
    // default is false and it allows to delete uploaded files
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    // this is the element where the remove button or text will be located
    dictRemoveFile: "<div><span class='fa fa-trash text-danger' style='font-size: 1.5em;cursor:pointer'></span></div>",
 
    /* the following solution failed
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')
    } */
});
```

What I have to do to solve this issue?

Comment: If you log `$('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')` does it look correct?

Comment: Do you mean making a console.log in the browser's console? I tried this way, I get undefined.

Comment: I did ya. That means you're not actually sending the token.

Comment: So if I put the class="dropzone dz" id="my-dropzone" in the form tag I send the token and if I put it inside a div I don't send the token. The big question is why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request) I see it being called
`X-CSRFToken` not `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. Try fixing that and uncommenting your header code.

The code I see in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/) for getting the token is
`document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value` try replacing yours with that. Just be sure you have `{% csrf_token %}` in your page somewhere.

Comment: I tried exactly what you have suggested :
headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')
}
But I still have the same problem. Maybe another mispelled keyword?

Comment: @Danilo edited post to include correct way to get token

Comment: Oh, great it worked now. So the correct line is `'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;`